# Server- Side condition not working for Interactive Grids in Oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I see that the server-side condition for Interactive grids, though returning false, is not stopping the process from executing. Is this a bug or Am i missing something?

This is observed when `Execute Condition = For Each Row`. This is working fine for the case of  `Execute Condition = Once`.

I'm using Oracle Apex version 19.1

[image]

Comment: Using APEX 18, I can confirm that the code you put in `PL/SQL Function Body` doesn't even get executed itself. Maybe use some kind of loop in your process code if you need to for example skip some rows.

Comment: @ThomasTschernich Thanks for confirming. Yes the code is not even executed. Must be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is a bug, your execute scope is set to created and modified rows, does the condition apply to new rows?

Comment: Yes when the scope is set to created and modified rows, the condition should apply to new (created) rows. But the server-side condition is not working as long as the execute condition is "For Each Row"

Comment: Yes, possibly a bug then